# Notepad++ add to every line

Tags: notepad++

I'm using Notepad++ and I can't figure this out :

I have numerous lines all starting with `http`. I need to add some text in front of it in every line.  Also, I need to add different text to the end of each line. Each line ends differently.

What is the fastest way to add text to the start and end of each line?

Comment: Replace with regular expressions. Replace `end of line` (I do not recall which symbol it is) with [myText]`end of line`

Comment: look http://notepad-plus-plus.org/ for how to use this tool

Comment: Do you want add the same text to each line?

Comment: use same text at start of each line

Comment: same text at end of each line. end text is different than start text though.   also I did look on how to use the tool and im lost, this why im asking. thank you for any help

Comment: Notepad2-mod CTRL+M lot easier

Answer (score 1114, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to bring up the Find/Replace Dialog.
2. Choose the `Regular expression` option near the bottom of the dialog.

To add a word, such as `test`, at the **beginning** of each line:

> 1. Type `^` in the `Find what` textbox
> 2. Type `test` in the `Replace with` textbox
> 3. Place cursor in the first line of the file to ensure all lines are affected
> 4. Click `Replace All` button

To add a word, such as `test`, at the **end** of each line:

> 1. Type `$` in the `Find what` textbox
> 2. Type `test` in the `Replace with` textbox
> 3. Place cursor in the first line of the file to ensure all lines are affected
> 4. Click `Replace All` button

Comment: You can replace only 6561963 lines.

Comment: While creating SQL-queries, I had to use \ as an escape character: `'\);`

Comment: To those who need to add a special character, you need to use \ as an escape character.
Special characters: ., +, *, ?, ^, $, (, ), [, ], {, }, |, \.

Answer (score 168):

1. Move your cursor to the start of the first line
2. Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and use the cursor <kbd>down</kbd> key to extend the selection to the end of the block

This allows you to type on every line simultaneously.

I found the solution above [here](https://superuser.com/questions/351121/add-a-string-to-every-line-of-a-selection).

I think this is much easier than using regex.

Comment: This will only work for the beginning of a line, if the lines are all different lengths

Comment: I was very pleased to discover that I could drag my mouse instead of using the down key and it still worked.  Even better, I can just scroll down to the final line I'm going to select and ctrl+alt+shift then click worked exactly like I hoped it would.

Comment: TBH this is really the only thing that keeps pushing me to move to Sublime editor...so many years of requests too, it's a shame.

Comment: Is there a way to do this at the end of lines of variable length, though?

Comment: For end of lines, it works the same way.  Move your cursor to where you need to type at the end of the line. As you hit Shift + Alt and drag your cursor down, you will see a vertical line extending.  When you are happy to stop, just let go and type what you need.  The thing you typed will all show up at the same "column" at the end of the lines.  This trick won't work if you want the text to appear at different "columns", i.e. all at 5 spaces after the end of the individual lines of different lengths.

Answer (score 40):

**Notepad++ Add Word To Start Of Every Line**

Follow this instruction to write anything at the start of every line with Notepad++

Open Notepad++,

Press **Cntrl**+**H** open the Find/Replace Dialog.

Now type **^** in the **Find what** textbox (Type ^ without any spaces)

Type anything(like in our example I am writing "John ") in the **Replace with** textbox (Write text one/more space for adding one/more space after your text in every line)

Select the **Regular Expression** option

Place your cursor in the first line of your file to ensure all lines are affected

Click **Replace All** button

[image]

[image]

**Notepad++ Add Text To End Of Every Line**

Follow this instruction to write anything at the end of every line with Notepad++

Open Notepad++,

Press **Cntrl**+**H** open the Find/Replace Dialog.

Now type **$** in the **Find what** textbox (Type $ without any spaces)

Type anything(like in our example I am writing " John") in the **Replace with** textbox (Write one/more space text for adding one/more space before your text in every line)

Select the **Regular Expression** option

Place your cursor in the first line of your file to ensure all lines are affected

Click **Replace All** button

[image]

[image]

For all Notepadd++ Tutorials: **[VISIT:)](http://www.joblesspanda.com/search/label/Notepad%20Plus%20Plus)**

Comment: This appears very similar to many other answers here. Can you [edit] it to explain what new insights your answer gives to the topic. Answers that just repeat existing information are not helpful. Answering is good but I recommend you look for questions with no accepted answers or with only a few poor (or incomplete) answers. Note that "Notepad++" only has one "d".

Answer (score 32):

Notepad++ has a very powerful editing capability.
(Today I'm searching for the similar function in Sublime Text), but for Notepad++, just hold **Alt** when you drag the mouse. What you type will then replace the selected column on every line. To insert without replacing existing text, use **Alt-Shift**.

[image]

Comment: This should be voted much higher. Because contrary to what one may think when reading "_editing_ the whole column", this allows adding text to the beginning of all lines without replacing anything.

Comment: I think you did a mistake there ;) @JimR Alt + Shift will overwrite the text and Alt inserts (at least for me)

Comment: control right mouse will column select in sublime text as you describe.

Answer (score 26):

Here is my answer. To add ');' to the end of each line I do 'Find What: $' and 'Replace with: \);' you need to do escape;
[image]

Answer (score 21):

You can **automatically do it** in Notepad++ (add text at the beginning and/or end of each line) **by using one regular expression** in Replace (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>):

[image]

**Explanation:** Expression `$1` in *Replace with* input denotes all the characters that include the round brackets `(.*)` in *Find what* regular expressin.

Tested, it works.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 20):

Well, I am posting this after such a long time but this will the easiest of all.

1. To add text at the beginning/a-certain-place-from-start for all lines, just click there and do ALT+C and you will get the below box. Type in your text and click OK and it's done.

   [image]
2. To add a certain text at end of all lines, do CTRL+F, and choose REPLACE. You will get the below box. Put in '$' in 'find what' and in 'replace with' type in your text.Make sure you choose 'regular expression' in the search mode (left down). Finally click 'replace all' and you are done.

[image]

Answer (score 17):

Open Notepad++, then click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>F</kbd>.

Choose Regular Expression

*Find What: "^" (which represents index of the each line -  "PREFIX").

Replace with : "anyText"*

[image]

For **Suffix** on each line: Follow the same steps as above "Replace ^ with $" . That's it.

Answer (score 5):

In order to do it in one go:

1. **Copy** and **paste** the following example text in your notepad++ window:

> http:\blahblah.com
>
> http:\blahnotblah.com
>
> http:\blahandgainblah.com

2. Press **Ctrl+H** on the notepad++ window
3. In the **Find what** box type: `^(.+)$`. Here ^ represents the start of the line. $ represents the end of the line. (.+) means any character in between the start and the end of the line and it would be group 1.
4. In the **Replace with** box type: `WhateverFrontText(\1)WhatEverEndText`. Here (\1) means whatever text in a line.
5. Check the *check box* **Wrap around**
6. Search mode: Regular expression
7. Result:

> WhateverFrontTexthttp:\blahblah.comWhatEverEndText
>
> WhateverFrontTexthttp:\blahnotblah.comWhatEverEndText
>
> WhateverFrontTexthttp:\blahandgainblah.comWhatEverEndText

8. Screenshot of the notepad++ options and result:
   [image]

Comment: Why are you putting `\1` inside parenthesis in "replace with"? Also it's better to use `$1`, `\1` is a very old practice.

Answer (score 4):

To append different text to the end of each line, you can use the plugin [ConyEdit](https://www.conyedit.com/) to do this.
With ConyEdit running in the background, follow these steps.

1. use the command line `cc.gl a` to get lines and store in an array named a.
2. use the command line `cc.aal //$a` to append after each line, using the contents of array a.

**Example**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you have thousands of lines, I guess the easiest way is like this:

-select the line that is the start point for your cursor

-while you are holding <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> select the line that is endpoint for your cursor

That's it. Now you have a giant cursor. You can write anything to all of these lines.

Answer (score 2):

Simply in the "Find what:" field, type `\r`. This means "Ends of the Row". In the "Replace with:" field, you put what you want for instance `.xml`

if you have several lines, and you are aiming to add that text to the end of the each line, you need to markup the option ". matches newline" in the "Search Mode" group box.

Example:

You have a file name list, but you want to add an extension like .xml. 
This would be what you need to do and Bang! One shot!:

[See the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZxlH.png)

Answer (score 2):

Please find the Screenshot below which Add a new word at the start and end of the line at a single shot

[image: adding a new word at the start & end of the every line in Notepad++ at a single shot]