# Add extra element to search & replace

Tags: notepad++

I got a question on how to add an object (for example ",") to a long list within my notepad++?

I got the following situation:

```
1,1,set: 1
2,5,set: 2
4,2,set: 1
5,2,set: 1
6,12,set: 12
7,13,set: 7
```

What I want is that for each line after `set: 1` and `set: 2` and so on, add a "," so that I will get the following result:

```
1,1,set: 1, <-- comma
2,5,set: 2, <-- comma
4,2,set: 1, <-- comma
5,2,set: 1, <-- comma
6,12,set: 12, <-- comma
7,13,set: 7, <-- comma and so on
```

Please keep in mind that the text <-- comma does not have to be added to the document. Perhaps this is not a hard thing to do but I could not find any clear examples on the internet. Perhaps you guys can help me solving this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notepad++ add to every line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003761/notepad-add-to-every-line)

Comment: Yep! Sorry! Thank you anyways! @Kobi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press Ctrl-H, replace `$` with `,`, set *Search Mode* to *Regular expression*, and click *Replace All*:

[image]