# Excel - exporting as TXT with text position

Tags: excel, notepad

I have several text files (about 6). All have the following format.

```
Column (Text position in txt file)
1-4 -> Code
6-72 -> Name
74-78 -> another code
80-81 -> another code
```

These text files I want to import into excel, so I can sort them after A-Z and inspect the duplicates. After doing so, I must delete a few duplicates and export this to ONE single txt file. This file must be saved in the exact same format as before. Unfortunately I cannot find anything in the Internet regarding this.

Could somebody help me?

Thanks and best regards
Dennis

Comment: Text to columns can handle fixed width fields. After manipulating the data, you could join into a single column, delete all but that column, and save as a text file. That (or something similar) should work. You can do this manually or (if this is a recurring scenario) write a VBA macro to do it. If you know a bit of programming -- you could forget about Excel and just do it in Python where it would require only about a dozen lines of code, perhaps less.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution!

1. First I combine the data in the excel file and manipulate it. After
   that I adjust the width of the columns, so no values overlap.
2. Then I save this as an .prn file.
3. This .prn file I open in notepad++ and manipulate the column
   position with help of SHIFT + ALT + Down to set multiple Cursors.
4. Now I got my file :-)

Thanks anyway!

Ressources:

[Export an Excel Spreadsheet as fixed width text file](https://superuser.com/questions/100433/export-an-excel-spreadsheet-to-fixed-width-text-file)

[Notepad Multiple Cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003761/notepad-add-to-every-line)

Comment: It is always fun when you can solve your own problem.