# How do I add 2 spaces to the beginning of every line in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Pretty much what it says in the title. I am trying to add 2 spaces to the beginning of every line of a very long list in Notepad++. I could do it manually, but it would be a serious pain. I'm sure there is some simple method I am not seeing.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notepad++ add to every line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003761/notepad-add-to-every-line)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple replacement you may do, in regex mode:

```
Find:    ^
Replace: (two spaces)
```

The above approach finds the (zero width) marker for the start of each line, and then replaces with two spaces, thereby inserting two spaces to the start of each line.

Comment: How do you adjust the RegEx to handle lines that begin with a tab? I need to add 2 spaces to a block of text, but lines beginning with a tab aren't working.

Comment: Match on `^\t` IIUC